# Store Query Results and Send Via Email VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to send via email the results of a query which has multiple rows. At this moment, the lines of code I have only return the first row of the query result.

```
Dim Campo As String, AltNova As String, Message As String
Query = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"

rsSQL.Open Query, DSN, adOpenStatic
Do While Not rsSQL.EOF
    Field1 = rsSQL("Field1").Value
    Field2 = rsSQL("Field2").Value
    rsSQL.MoveNext
Loop
rsSQL.Close
Set rsSQL = Nothing

Message = Field1 & Field2
```

I know it doesn't work like this, but I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: You should update `Message`  in the loop (something like `Message = Message & Field1 & Field2 & vbNewLine`)

Comment: Why not just use the `GetString()` method after selecting only the desired fields?

Comment: It looks to me that in the code given Message should have the values from the LAST row. Since as noted Message is not updated inside the loop. If you are seeing it with the first values are you sure the query is actually returning multiple rows?